# Create table that invokes a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, proxy, migration, sybase

I'm migrating SPs from Sybase to SQL Server and I have a case where they use "proxy tables" which are used to internally invoke a SP whenever they are used in a query...

The syntax used to create the proxy table is something like this:

```
USE myDatabase
go
sp_addobjectdef proxy_table_name, 'loopback.myDatabase..sp_name', 'rpc'
go
CREATE EXISTING TABLE proxy_table_name
(
    col1       int NOT NULL,
    col2       char(2) NOT NULL,
    col3       varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    _id_sp     int NULL
)
LOCK ALLPAGES
go
```

And the SP definition something like this:

```
CREATE procedure sp_search_intermediary_agent
(
      @param_default_1      char(1)  = 'N',  
      @param_default_2      bit      = 0, 
      @i_id_query           int 
)
as
begin
........ (some code here)


  select col1, col2, col3 from table_where_data_is 
  where  id_table = @i_id_query
  return 0
end
go
```

And the proxy table is used within the query as if it were a normal table...

```
select col1, col2, col3,....
from  table_1, proxy_table_name
where table_1.id_field = proxy_table_name._id_sp
```

Please, any ideas about how to migrate this "proxy tables" to SQL Server 2008??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a [table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).